# In Unity3D, when building to web, model gets distorted

Tags: unity, models, webapp

As the title says, when I build for web, the character model gets distorted, but while in the editor, it's completely fine. Here are the images:

Before, in play mode:

[image: Before, in play mode:]

After, in the web build:

[image]

As you can see, there is a big distortion in the legs area. This may be because of the model, or that I am not building it to the web correctly. I am not sure. This model is a .blend, and resizing the game window while playing does not reproduce this effect. Even a while back, when I was testing it out, I built it to web, went on the same site as I did when this problem happened to play it, and everything was fine. Any help would be appreciated, since I am really drawing a blank here. Please tell me if you need any info I may have missed. Thank you!